# Making a query with doctrine in Symfony2 gives Semantical error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to make a query in my Symfony project, I make it with the following code:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $countUnreadPm = $em->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('count(*)')
    ->from('Privatemessage', 'pmid')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

However this gets me a semantical error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 21 near 'Privatemessage': Error: Class 'Privatemessage' is not defined.
```

The entity class is named 'Privatemessage' so no problems there. What is the issue?

Comment: Do you have a entity class?

Comment: Hey @stijn26 You have successfully solve the problem?

Comment: Yes I just tried your solution and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**count(pmid)** - DQL count objects.

**->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Privatemessage')** - Full path to entity eg. AcmeDemoBundle

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$countUnreadPm = $em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('count(pmid)')
->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Privatemessage', 'pmid')
->getQuery()
->getResult(); // or ->getSingleScalarResult(); For integer value.
```